# Calculate distance between of one point to every other points in a position data

Tags: python, pandas

I have a football player position data. Now i have to calculate the distance from player A to other player B, C, D in the dataset and arrange the column based on the order of how close they are. The data looks like this

```
ts1 = np.random.rand(10)
ts2 = np.random.rand(10)
ts3 = np.random.rand(10)
ts4 = np.random.rand(10)
ts5 = np.random.rand(10)
ts6 = np.random.rand(10)
ts7 = np.random.rand(10)
ts8 = np.random.rand(10)
d = {'A_x': ts1, 'A_y': ts2,'B_x': ts3, 'B_y':ts4, 'C_x':ts5, 'C_y':ts6,
                         'D_x':ts7, 'D_y':ts8}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

So the data will look like this
df

```
A_x       A_y       B_x       B_y       C_x       C_y       D_x  \
```

0  0.423073  0.980156  0.513101  0.842604  0.196775  0.482592  0.419169
1  0.363428  0.520050  0.799685  0.184905  0.919634  0.483978  0.313876
2  0.029975  0.010020  0.739184  0.443437  0.884022  0.328365  0.448889
3  0.674032  0.399175  0.512700  0.697177  0.414588  0.915752  0.095993
4  0.962292  0.939266  0.466896  0.406284  0.922713  0.405991  0.798676
5  0.929178  0.936950  0.886348  0.639929  0.518401  0.848468  0.985375
6  0.290297  0.398941  0.896976  0.775312  0.976815  0.546444  0.937562
7  0.332582  0.191384  0.075902  0.645477  0.433419  0.917658  0.850850
8  0.817298  0.612915  0.903426  0.662707  0.825628  0.648411  0.556697
9  0.383350  0.715573  0.994297  0.491445  0.785036  0.110449  0.072658

```
    D_y
```

0  0.909314
1  0.235216
2  0.284318
3  0.022496
4  0.756945
5  0.772382
6  0.850470
7  0.586915
8  0.799697
9  0.391556

So the 1st question is how can i calculate distance for each pairs of column? So the output should have 3 columns like:
A-B     A-C      A-D
And the 2nd question is how can i generate a new position table that for each row, the column will be ordered by how close they are to A. So the new table will have column like
A_x     A_y     nearest1st_X   nearest1st_y    nearest2nd_x   nearest2nd_y nearest3d_x    nearest3d_y
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can use numpy.linalg.norm:

```
dist = numpy.linalg.norm(a-b)
```

or There's a function for that in SciPy, it's called Euclidean

```
from scipy.spatial import distance
a = (1,2,3)
b = (4,5,6)
dst = distance.euclidean(a,b)
```

and include this in a loop to read each column

**EDIT :**

It's maybe not the best way but an example :

```
import numpy as np

num_P=10
ts1 = np.random.rand(num_P)
ts2 = np.random.rand(num_P)
ts3 = np.random.rand(num_P)
ts4 = np.random.rand(num_P)
ts5 = np.random.rand(num_P)
ts6 = np.random.rand(num_P)
ts7 = np.random.rand(num_P)
ts8 = np.random.rand(num_P)
d = {'A_x': ts1, 'A_y': ts2,'B_x': ts3, 'B_y':ts4, 'C_x':ts5, 'C_y':ts6,
                         'D_x':ts7, 'D_y':ts8}
f={}
for i in range(num_P):
    print i
    nkey="postion "+ str(i)
    f[nkey]=[]
    position=[item[i] for item in d.values()]
        for n,k in enumerate(position[:-1]): 
        a=position[n]
        b=position[n+1]         
        dist = np.linalg.norm(a-b)
        f[nkey].append(dist)
```

Comment: I know how to calculate the distance but do u know how can i calculate them simultaniously at the same time?

Comment: you can calculate each distance in a `for` loop reading trough your `df`

Comment: see Edit in the post